# parsley.js do not validate several validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have written some code for validating textarea, but it does not work for multiple validations for one CKeditor textarea. Here is my code:

```
<div id="insdescription" class="col-md-12 input-group" >
                                <textarea type="text" id="insdescription1" name="insdescription"  class="form-control" rows="5"  data-parsley-errors-container="#insdescription-errors" data-parsley-required-message="Это поле необходимо!"  data-parsley-minlength-message="Введите не менее 10 символов!" ><?= $instructors['description']; ?></textarea>
    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('insdescription1');
    </script>
    </div>
   <div id="insdescription-errors"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
                  CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
                    $('#insdescription1').attr('minlength', '10');
                    $('#insdescription1').attr('required', '', );
                    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (instance) {
                        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change", function (e) {
                            for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                                CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
                                $('form').parsley().validate();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    });
                </script>
```

Actually, it works for required="" validation. But it does not work for minlength="10". Here is the screenshot [image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own Parsley custom validator.

Indeed, you are validating the content of the **CKEDITOR** and so, for instance, the string:

```
1234
```

becomes:

```
<p>1234</p>
```

And the last string is longer than 4.

The custom validator can be:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('minTextSize', {
     validateString: function(_value, minTextSize, parsleyInstance) {
         if (!window.FormData) {
             alert('You are making all developpers in the world cringe. Upgrade your browser!');
             return true;
         }
         var txt = $(_value).text().trim();
         return txt.length > minTextSize;
     },
     requirementType: 'integer'
 });
```

and so, your textarea will be:

```
<textarea id="insdescription1" name="insdescription" class="form-control" rows="5"
    data-parsley-trigger="keyup"
    data-parsley-min-text-size="10"
    data-parsley-errors-container="#insdescription-errors"
    data-parsley-required-message="Это поле необходимо!rrr"
    data-parsley-min-text-size-message="Введите не менее 10 символов!xxx"></textarea>
```

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcte344u/4/).

PS: I added chars at end of your messages because I don't understand your language and I needed to test.

Comment: @JavidAbbasov If i input only one char i see the message, only when I input more than 10 chars the message disappears. Did you test the fiddle?

Comment: I tested the fiddle, but in my code it did not work 

Comment: @JavidAbbasov  Pay attention to the differences. Something must differ. See the HTML, the libraries.....

Comment: @JavidAbbasov The **textarea** changed. For instance I removed the **type......**

Comment: it is very interesting. When I write 1 letter it gives an error https://yadi.sk/i/Il6qfonk3MfSyV , but when I write 2 or more, it does not work https://yadi.sk/i/lyfPafBn3MfT35

Comment: @JavidAbbasov I understand but if you don't create a fiddle I cannot test and fix your code. Like you can see it works in my jsFiddle. Please, help me to help you. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I have replaced `<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/vendor/parsley.min.js"></script>` code from footer to header, it has worked. But I  do not understand why?

Comment: @JavidAbbasov That beacuse you are using **CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady'**